# ObjectMapper Adds Escape Characters When Writing String to Outputstream

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I have the below piece of code where I write a string to an output stream with Jackson's ObjectMapper.

```
OutputStream outputStream = new PrintStream(System.out);
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String output = "{\"test\":\"mytest/123\"}";
objectMapper.writeValue(outputStream, output);
```

When I run this code, the output stream prints the following string, where there are additional escape characters.

```
"{\"vfi\":\"test/mytest/123\"}"
```

How can I avoid the escape characters here? I am not using ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString but still they get printed. Appreciate any help.

Comment: You are serializing a string. A string starts and ends with `"`. Any embedded quotes must be escaped. If you want to print a string, don't serialize it, but print it directly – without serializing first. What _is your expected_ output?

Comment: @knittl I need to write the string to an outputstream to return it via an AWS Lambda. Is there no way to remove those escape characters writing it to outputstream?

Comment: There is: print directly, without serializing. Why are you using ObjectMapper to serialize a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *serializing* a Java string as JSON string. JSON strings must start and end with `"` and any embedded quotes *must* be escaped. (ref: https://json.org)

You have two options:

1. Print the string directly, without serializing via ObjectMapper

   ```
   OutputStream outputStream = new PrintStream(System.out);
   String output = "{\"test\":\"mytest/123\"}";
   outputStream.println(output);
   ```
2. Serialize an object, e.g. Map, to a JSON string

   ```
   OutputStream outputStream = new PrintStream(System.out);
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   Map<String, String> output = Map.of("test", "mytest/123");
   objectMapper.writeValue(outputStream, output);
   ```

   It's also possible to define a custom class to represent your JSON structure. Depending on the complexity of your structure and other requirements, this could be the preferrable option.

   ```
   class MyOutput {
     private final String test;
     public MyOutput(final String test) { this.test = test; }
     public String getTest() { return test; }
   }

   OutputStream outputStream = new PrintStream(System.out);
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   MyOutput output = new MyOutput("mytest/123");
   objectMapper.writeValue(outputStream, output);
   ```